# Scala runtime plugin system

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-compiler

I'm working on simple application server and i want to make extending plugin system. For building plugins i'm planning create special wizard that will generate scala source files. I'm want automatic compilation and loading this files for include their buisness logic in to my application server. Is it possible done in Scala and that i'm must read and do for realise this idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices.

1. Use OSGi.  It's *designed* for plugins, and has some very nice features for loading/unloading services, handling cross-service dependencies, etc.  On the down side, it does mean that you'll have to pre-compile your plugins and wrap them in a jar file along with a valid OSGi manifest.
2. Use [ScalaScriptEngine](https://code.google.com/p/scalascriptengine/) (or something equivalent).  It seems to already handle all of your requirements :)

Comment: Thanks alot for the tip about ScalaScriptEngine, its look greate for my purpose!